# Laravel Authenticate middleware flash message

Tags: php, laravel, session, flash-message

In my auth middleware I have the following code:

```
        if (! Auth::user()->enabled) {
            Auth::logout();
            // $request->session()->flash('Test', 'Test');
            // return redirect()->route('site::home');

            return redirect()->route('site::home')->withFlash('Test');
        }
```

I'm trying to redirect the user back to the login page with a flash message but whenever I look into the session() there's no flash message.

What am I doing wrong? it feels like i've tried every variation of a flash message and none of it seems to work

Comment: How are you accessing this flash variable? Paste that code here.

Comment: I'm just dumping out the session with {{ dd(Session::all()) }}

Answer (score 1):

```
return redirect()->route('site::home')->flash('This is a message!');
```

OR

```
return \Redirect::back()->withWarning( 'Message you want show in View' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
return redirect()->route('route_name')->with('custom_key', 'Custom Message');
```