# Laravel 8.x: redirect after Login to previous location, with all Input data reinserted

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect

I'm trying to build an app with Laravel that allows users to book flights with several locations included.

For autentication I'm using the laravel/ui package.

To complete the booking, if the user is not logged, he's redirected to login form and if the credentials are valid he returns to the previous page.

**The problem is once the user returns back, after login, the data passed previously with the POST request at that page do not exist anymore.**

I put a flowchart to explain better what I would like to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeF3e.jpg

So, what should I do to reload that page, with the previous POST values?

Comment: You can use temporary table for this purpose.

Comment: You can use session too.

Comment: How about saving the post data in the session inside the `auth` middleware ?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should redirect user back using withInput(), eg.:

`return back()->withInput();`

Here you can find a more detailed explanation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-with-input

Comment: I tried to flash the data to the session from the middleware, but I can't retrieve them after the submit of the login form

Comment: I don't know how are you flashing data to session, but maybe this post should give you an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640669/laravel-authenticate-middleware-flash-message.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `temp` table to save this data before redirecting the user to log in with a unique value in the session held in both the new user row and the previous temp table.

Then after redirection load the page with user temp data in the temp table through that key.

It would be nice if you do a corn job to delete these temp data daily.

Comment: Maybe I'll try to check what is the better solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding GET method to the page to book the flight, then I pass the input data from the middleware as route params to the login form.
After the login form is submitted, if the user log successfully, that data are flashed to the session and are available after redirect to the previous page.
I think is not the best solution because the data are shown in the URL in login page, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do your submission with javascript and take advantage of the browser storage to persisit the temporary data. You can delete this once you are done.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve this

In the booking form blade file use form field values with variables having `@` before name like below, so that whenever the variable is available it will display the values

[image]

After submitting booking details store the form fields in **redis**.
You can do this process in the middleware itself.
Make another middleware for storing the form data in redis and then laravel's auth middleware.

After successful login you can redirect to booking page and in booking controller, store the **redis** values in another variable then delete the created **redis** fields and send the form data to view

Delete **redis** fields in normal booking submit function also in the controller if fields exists.

Laravel redis docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis

Answer (score 0):

When you make your first **POST** request, in the receiving controller, store passed form data in the session.
Then, you can retrieve (or retrieve-and-delete) data from session and repopulate form fields.

For example:

**.. views/flight.blade.php**

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <input type="text" name="field" value="{{ session('flightData')['field'] ?? '' }}">
  <input type="text" name="another" value="{{ session('flightData')['another'] ?? '' }}">
  <button type="submit">SEND</button>   
</form>
```

**.. Controllers/FlightController.php**

```
public function your_post_method(Request $request) {

  ...
  session()->put('flightData', $request->all());
  ...

}
```

Obviously you can get Session data in the controller, process it and then pass it to your view

You can use `session()->pull('key', 'default')` to retrieve and delete stored data or, after retrieving data, you can delete it with `session()->forget('key')`.

Remember that the Session is per-user.

Check Laravel Session docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#storing-data

Answer (score 0):

So, from the question you are using the laravel's default authentication system also from your question you are saying that after the authentication, the user redirects back to the same page from where you are passing your input data through post request.

First step : Modify the "Authenticate" Middleware - in its redirect method put the post request data in session :

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            session()->put('request', $request->all());
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Here the only thing added is this code :

> session()->put('request', $request->all());

Second Step : Go to **LoginController.php** and override the function "**authenticated()**" from the trait "**AuthenticatesUsers**" don't forget to use **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;** in **LoginController** : and redirect your user to appropriate page withInput like below :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class LoginController extends Controller{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    // this is authenticated method which is overridden method of AuthenticatesUsers trait this function
    // is responsible to redirect the logged in user to proper page 
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect()->route('your_page')->withInput(session()->pull('request')); 
    }
}
```

Third Step : Don't forget to access your data in blade through old() method :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Title of Post" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}">
```

Fourth Step : test it out your post request page has been repopulated .

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
return back()->withInput();
```

In blade you can use in values `{{ old('inputName','Default Value') }}`